# One liner awk html tag replace "''>" with "''> " with gsub

Tags: html, awk, escaping, gsub

I've been racking my brain with this for the past half an hour and everything I've tried so far has failed miserably!

Within an html file, there is a field within  tags, but the field itself is not separated with a space from the > sign so it's hard to read with awk. I would basically like to add a single space after the opening  tag, but gsub and awk are refusing to cooperate.

I've tried

```
awk 'gsub("class\\\'\\\'>","class\\\'\\\'>")' filename
```

since one backslash is needed to escape the single quote, the second to escape the backslash itself, and the third to escape the sequence \' but Terminal (I'm working on a Mac) refuses to execute, and instead goes in the next line awaiting some other input from me.

Please help :(

Comment: the backslashes come in threes, not in twos as is displayed here.

Comment: Format your code as code then, instead of quote :]

Comment: What's wrong with just `awk 'gsub(">","> ")'`?

Comment: Yeah, what are all the backslashes and single quotes for?

Comment: similar questions every week. Try searching. Good luck.

Comment: @Ansari - the only thing wrong with it is that I'm an IDIOT!!! Thanks man!!

Comment: @Ansari : what's wrong with `awk 'gsub(">","> ")'` ? any line that didn't have any `HTML` tags would fail to print.  taking its zero-th power should fix it :::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::: `awk 'gsub(">","> ")^_'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bash, single quotes accept *absolutely no kind of escape*. Suppose e.g. I write this command:

```
$ echo '\''
>
```

Bash will consider the string opened by `'` closed at the second `'`, generating a string containing only `\`. The next `'`, then, is considered the opening of a new string, so bash expects for more input in the next line (signalled by the `>`).

If you are not aware of this fact, you may think that the string after the `echo` command below will be open yet, but it is closed:

```
$ echo 'will this string contain a single quote like \'
will this string contain a single quote like \
```

So, when you write

```
'gsub("class\\\'\\\'>","class\\\'\\\'> ")'
```

you are writing the string `gsub("class\\\` concatenated with a backslash and a quote (`\'`); then a greater than signal. After this, the `","` is interpreted as a string containing a comma, because the single quote of the beginning of the expression was closed before. For now, the result is:

```
gsub("class\\\\'>,
```

After the comma, you have the string `class`, followed by a backslash and a quote, followed by another backslash and another quote, and finally by a greater than symbol and a space. This is the current string:

```
gsub("class\\\\'>,class\'\'>
```

This is no valid awk expression! Anyway, it gets worse: the double quote `"` will start a string, which will contain a closing parenthesis and a single quote, *but this string is never closed!*

**Summing up**, your problem is that, if you opened a string with `'` in Bash, it will be forcedly close at the next `'`, no matter how many backslashes you put before it.

**Solution**: you can make some tricks opening and closing strings with `'` and `"` but it will become cumbersome quickly. My suggested solution is to put your awk expression in a file. Then, use the `-f` flag from awk - this flag will make awk to execute the following file:

```
$ cat filename # The file to be changed
class''>
class>
class''>
$ cat mycode.awk  # The awk script
gsub("class''>", "class''>[PSEUDOSPACE]")
$ awk -f mycode.awk filename  # THE RESULT!
class''>[PSEUDOSPACE]
class''>[PSEUDOSPACE]
```

If you do not want to write a file, use the so called [here documents](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
$ awk -f- filename <<EOF 
gsub("class''>", "class''>[PSEUDOSPACE]")
EOF
class''>[PSEUDOSPACE]
class''>[PSEUDOSPACE]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are escaping the `'`, so you are not finishing the command.  For example:

```
echo \' > foo
```

echoes a single quote into the file named foo, and

```
echo \\\' > foo
```

writes a single backslash followed by a single quote.

In particular, you cannot escape a single quote inside a string, so

```
'foo\'bar'
```

is the string `foo\` followed by the string `bar` followed by an unmatched open quote.  It is exactly the same as writing `"foo\\"bar'`